# TypeScript Generic Parameter Type Extending Another Type

Tags: typescript

I'm having issues compiling the following. it's included in an old project with the comment - "This is a TS1.8 feature. Leave it in to ensure the environment is running the right ts".

```
  function assign<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
        for (let id in source) {
            target[id] = source[id]; // error TS2322: Type 'U[Extract<keyof U, string>]' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof U, string>]'.
        } 
        return target;
    }
```

I'm compiling it with the following command

```
tsc -p tsconfig.json
```

And this tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": [
    "Scripts/TypeScripts/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "watch": false
  }
}
```

`tsc -v` yields `Version 3.4.5`.

When I [try it in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), I also see the error, which makes me think that it is indeed invalid code. However, this poses the questions what was I thinking when I wrote that comment and how come it's been compiling for 2 years (or has it??)

So - my question: Is this valid TS Code? If not, was it ever?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look valid to me, but I haven't used TS1.8 (I think I started in 2.4 or so).  The problem with having `T extends U` is that, while all of `U`'s property keys must also exist in `T`, the *values* at those property keys could be *narrower*.  That is, given this:

```
function badAssign<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
  for (let id in source) {
    target[id] = source[id] as any; // assert to remove error, but
  }
  return target;
}
```

You can do this:

```
interface Ewe {
  w: string;
  x: number;
  y: boolean;
}
interface Tee extends Ewe {
  w: "hey";
  x: 1;
  y: true;
  z: object;
}

const t: Tee = { w: "hey", x: 1, y: true, z: {} };
const u: Ewe = { w: "you", x: 2, y: false };
const newT = badAssign(t, u); // compiles, but
newT.w // "hey" at compile time, "you" at runtime !! 
newT.x // 1 at compile time, 2 at runtime !!
newT.y // true at compile time, false at runtime !!
```

That's bad... by assigning `source[id]` to `target[id]` you are assuming that the property type of `target[id]` is *the same as or wider than* the type of `source[id]`, but when `T extends U` it means the opposite: `target[id]` is *the same as or narrower than* the type of `source[id]`.  So you've lied to the compiler.

The way I'd fix this is by replacing `U` with `Pick<T, K>` for some `K` that extends `keyof T`.  That guarantees that every key of `target` exists on `source` as before, and additionally it guarantees that for every key of `target`, the value of the corresponding property of `source` is assignable to it:

```
function assign<T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, source: Pick<T, K>): T {
  for (let id in source) {
    target[id] = source[id]; // okay
  }
  return target;
}
```

This catches the error of the bad call:

```
assign(t, u); // now an error, string is not assignable to "hey"
```

But still lets you use `assign()` as presumably intended:

```
let target = { a: "hey", b: 123, c: true };
let source = { a: "you", c: false };
const ret = assign(target, source);
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYBMCCBnbMDmYAPACqICmAHlOWOtogKoA0TAfABRSoBO+5UAFyISrbHBA8I5YYwCUwsgG8AUIkTA4PRBwA2AxDHSGk4ydLmJV69dz4CA2kYC6iALyIzU8k-SvUDKhgAJ4A3IgA9BGIAdjkPFCIUHCIPOQAtnAAbuQUPDxarMggUGqIAL5laVCSSHb8UKEqlSowYDQ8wKjSiACiAO651oj9wthQPG34TeqUwmAg6cjxM4jBwshwcPpBTZVtHV09JOS5VDR0DANDZaOIAEQAFuTB96tziACMq+tJPCDkVYAL2EcGQACtyNA9ioVBAEOMkopTu4rCNhE8XvdWB9PqxfhMAawQVZyhUmvCwIiQMJrqilOiHsEJNjEB8AEz44RdXRxclwhGJMDkfpkDxoLC4AhgLisEBycJRRDw9IABxg+mwRRKKmFooAdP1ItFMa8YokVer9EkYOlyKx7syQPdzalwLA7YgAIRexC6kUkfWUY1fV2WjW5D32xDs13-dq23I+-0G4Ihwm5VAWuBqiM2u2sHl8rNuhOe5MqUCQWAIGJSwikVgAaQo1Fo9EQAGsXnBgCJOPUBIoxBJvMIAAowCCdxuIJtsBQiKxlTTaPQGIwmTyjizLmxJXgNXyuDxeaTHxXROCd1DBMqVdTVWoH+yNZqw2LS2WIeWXxBgOAjSCPICh4MQJimQwGAAxJP0IVBkGtZIHmeV5YX0RJB0SDwGVQDFUNZZBhE+dkAGZWAgYQM35DDt3MXIcJiDEnVZSiNFQXlcnKClBVSAwPDgmUsJHeiFRUIA)

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I was kind of wondering if it was a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you inserted it as a guard to throw errors if TypeScript < v1.8 used.

Via "What's new in TypeScript" for v1.8, subsection "[Type parameters as constraints](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-parameters-as-constraints)":

> With TypeScript 1.8 it becomes possible for a type parameter
>   constraint to reference type parameters from the same type parameter
>   list. Previously this was an error. This capability is usually
>   referred to as F-Bounded Polymorphism.

```
Example
function assign<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
assign(x, { b: 10, d: 20 });
assign(x, { e: 0 });  // Error
```

Comment: ah! Yes, that's very likely where I got it from. So, it was valid in 1.8 but isn't now?