# Can one map a generic TypeScript type to another based on its generic parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a family of APIs that contain a variety of related generic types (and associated generic type constraints). I've synthesized an example and pasted it below, using well-known types to emulate some of the constructs just for illustration.

When working with these types, I often want to create a type from another type, reusing the generic type parameters of the referenced type. The operation is analogous to the way that an interface can constrain its property types based on the generic types supplied to its definition (and you'll see in the code example that this is what I'm doing as a workaround).

```
type Properties = { [name: string]: string }

interface SomeGeneric<A,B extends Properties,C extends HTMLElement> {
    someConcreteMethod: () => A
    someOtherConcreateMethod: (b: B) => void
    aConcreteProperty: C

    //  Fake properties, don't really exist at runtime, just to allow type derivation
    //  This is obviously terrible. Is there anything better?
    relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<A,B>
    anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<A,C>
    thirdRelatedInterface?: ThirdRelatedInterface<A,B,C>
}

interface RelatedInterface<A,B extends Properties> {
    yetAnotherMethod: (a: A, b: B) => void
}

interface AnotherRelatedInterface<A,C extends HTMLElement> {
    oneMoreMethod: (c: C) => A
}

interface ThirdRelatedInterface<A,B extends Properties,C extends HTMLElement> {
    thirdMethod: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => () => void

    //  Fake properties again
    relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<A,B>
    anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<A,C>
}

type ConcreteB = { name: string };

interface SomeConcreteType extends SomeGeneric<string,ConcreteB,HTMLDivElement> {}

//  So I have a family of related types, all generic, pertaining to one another. In this example, I've simplified it,
//  by making one type the canonical type (SomeGeneric). In my domain, that's not really true (you can see below I
//. create a type based on a ThirdRelatedInterface type also), although I could obviously pick one if I had to do that.
//. I've considered trying to base everything on SomeGeneric (and had the other types receive a type parameter that
//. extends SomeGeneric<A,B,C> rather than the type parameters A, B, and C themselves) but because these types all
//. have standalone use cases it would force me to declare useless unneeded type parameters when creating the
//. standalone types.

interface SomeConcreteRelatedInterfaceVerbosely extends RelatedInterface<string,ConcreteB> {}
interface AnotherConcreteRelatedInterfaceVerbosely extends AnotherRelatedInterface<string,HTMLDivElement> {}
interface ThirdConcreteRelatedInterfaceVerbosely extends ThirdRelatedInterface<string,ConcreteB,HTMLDivElement> {}

//  This is the only way I've been able to find to derive the related types without repeating the generic type parameters.
//. Because I have a family of related types, they all have synthetic, fake, type-inference-only properties like these.
//  Is there a better way?

type SomeConcreteRelatedInterfaceDeclaratively = SomeConcreteType["relatedInterface"]
type AnotherConcreteRelatedTypeDeclaratively = SomeConcreteType["anotherRelatedInterface"]
type ThirdConcreteTypeDeclaratively = SomeConcreteType["thirdRelatedInterface"]

type DerivedFromThirdTypeDeclaratively = ThirdConcreteTypeDeclaratively["anotherRelatedInterface"]
```

This is obviously horrendous for a number of reasons, the chief one being that now the compiler thinks these objects **have** properties of these types, when in fact I am just using the property "definitions" to do the transform I can't figure out how to do, from one constrained generic type to another.

This doesn't seem to correspond to the "mapped types" [feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which has to do with iterating over keys of a type. Nor can I find anything in the [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) documentation that talks about how to use the type constraint. (See below about one SO question that extracts a type parameter from a generic type, though, using `infer`.)

### Prior related questions

There are several questions that address the TypeScript situation where someone wants to make one generic type dependent on another via a constraint (see, for example, [TypeScript Generic Parameter Type Extending Another Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895334/typescript-generic-parameter-type-extending-another-type)), but I have not successfully found one that deals with making generic types dependent upon one another in different types.

The one thing I found that at least directly manipulates generic type parameters is [Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type), which illustrates how to transform an `Array` type to the type of its element (which is a generic parameter):

```
        export type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> =
            ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;
```

So that's definitely more analogous to what I want to do, although I want to then somehow transform the extracted type(s) further into one of my related types. And I must confess that I have not yet gotten my brain around how `infer` works, so I don't quite understand how I might use it, or whether it would apply.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545039/typescript-infer-generic-types-in-generic-type-constraint) about types that have their generic constraints based on generic types (and the desire to use the generic type parameter's parameters) also gets at something slightly analogous, but still pertains to a single type. Something about that solution might apply, though.

Comment: So do you basically want to get type for relatedInterface,anotherRelatedInterface, ... from `SomeGeneric` without declaring these properties in it?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR7z7N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I believe it certainly advances things forward. Because I have several types in this family, I might need more than one GetRelatedInterfaces, because several types can be mapped to related interfaces.

And I think I'd have to dereference them a level, usually, in order to use them. (I wouldn't be able to use `GetRelatedInterface` directly, I'd probably rename it `GetRelatedInterfaces` and then end up using `GetRelatedInterfaces['relatedInterface']` and so forth.

But I think it's still better than repeating the related types everywhere. And maybe I (or we) can tighten it.

Comment: Given the question, I'm unsurprised `infer` is involved, as it did seem like the only reference I found to an analogous need used it.

Comment: To clarify, in my above example, I'd need one of these *both* for SomeGeneric and for ThirdRelatedInterface, because I need to derive (in the English sense, not the "subclass" sense) types from both of those. But it's a library, even if these types proliferate a bit, I like that this approach (1) separates the "fake" types used for declaration/inference from real runtime types and (2) prevents the repetition of the generics "coordinates" all over the place (my original aim).

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. Could you provide a more complex test case so we can work on it? If the only concerning part is that you have to access interfaces through `['relatedInterface']`, we can definitely have a wrapper for each of the interfaces. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: So you mean that you want to be able to use this type against something else similar to `SomeGeneric`, but not exactly it?

Comment: Will your types always have 3 generic parameters?

Comment: Sure, the test case has the complexity I mean already -- both `SomeGeneric` and `ThirdRelatedInterface` have the "synthetic" type-inference-only properties. So I'd probably need GetSomeGenericRelatedInterface and GetThirdRelatedInterfaceRelatedInterface with the stuff analogous you did for the first.

But I think even that -- having to do it a few times -- is still a massive improvement.

Comment: And no, they don't always have three. I think the biggest has four, and several have three, two, and one of those, and the types are constantly being transformed between one another.

Comment: are the type constraints of the generic parameters the same for all types?
`A, B extends Properties,C extends HTMLElement`

Comment: yes, the type constraints remain consistent amongst the family of types

Comment: let me do some improvements then

Comment: What is the type of the fourth argument?

Comment: essentially `any`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with a better thing other than what you have proposed with GetSomeGenericRelatedInterface and GetThirdRelatedInterfaceRelatedInterface. If that's okay for you I can write an answer explaining

Comment: Let's do it, it's a start. Maybe someone can improve on it.

Comment: One improvement I'm considering is taking your structure and making a `ToType` interface that can convert *multiple* types to the target type. So if we look at ThirdRelatedInterface and SomeGeneric, they both can create the same two types. I *think* with the ternary syntax (I forget the TS term) I can create a single definition that maps both to a single type. This enables avoiding the awkward ['relatedInterface'] syntax.

Comment: If you make it in a better way, I would be interested to see, ping me if you'll be able to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253667/discussion-between-david-p-caldwell-and-wonderflame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently, there is no way to get the generic parameters of the type/interface without knowing the type itself. Thus there won't be a perfect solution to this problem.

One option is to have a generic type for each kind of interface related to other interfaces. We must use [infer keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to achieve this. You can interpret `infer` as a variable declaration.

Example from docs:

```
type Flatten<Type> = Type extends Array<infer Item> ? Item : Type;
```

In simple words, `infer` declares a parameter similar to a placeholder, which would evaluate the left and right sides of the condition:

`Array<string> extends Array<infer R>`, `R` has to be `string` for the equation. We can also write some constraints on the inferred parameter:

`infer R extends string`, then the compiler will treat `R` as a `string` not an unknown parameter.

We will use it in the same manner but with more parameters, which doesn't change the logic at all. Suppose `T` extends `SomeGeneric<any, any, any>`:

```
 T extends SomeGeneric<
    infer A extends string,
    infer B extends Properties,
    infer C extends HTMLElement
  >
```

This way, we get all three parameters of the `T` with the correct constraints (`string`, `Properties`, `HTMLElement`). Then we can pass their parameters to appropriate interfaces.

Getter for `SomeGeneric`:

```
type GetSomeGenericRelatedInterfaces<T extends SomeGeneric<any, any, any>> =
  T extends SomeGeneric<
    infer A extends string,
    infer B extends Properties,
    infer C extends HTMLElement
  >
    ? {
        relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<A, B>;
        anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<A, C>;
        thirdRelatedInterface: ThirdRelatedInterface<A, B, C>;
      }
    : never;
```

Getter for `ThirdRelatedInterface`:

```
type GetThirdRelatedInterfaces<T extends ThirdRelatedInterface<any, any, any>> =
  T extends ThirdRelatedInterface<
    infer A extends string,
    infer B extends Properties,
    infer C extends HTMLElement
  >
    ? {
        relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<A, B>;
        anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<A, C>;
      }
    : never;
```

Common wrapper:

```
type GetRelatedInterfaces<T> = T extends SomeGeneric<any, any, any>
  ? GetSomeGenericRelatedInterfaces<T>
  : T extends ThirdRelatedInterface<any, any, any>
  ? GetThirdRelatedInterfaces<T>
  : never;
```

Usage:

```
type ConcreteB = { name: string };

interface SomeConcreteType
  extends SomeGeneric<string, ConcreteB, HTMLDivElement> {}

interface ThirdConcreteRelatedInterfaceVerbosely
  extends ThirdRelatedInterface<string, ConcreteB, HTMLDivElement> {}


// type Case1 = {
//   relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<string, ConcreteB>;
//   anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<string, HTMLDivElement>;
//   thirdRelatedInterface: ThirdRelatedInterface<
//     string,
//     ConcreteB,
//     HTMLDivElement
//   >;
// };
type Case1 = GetRelatedInterfaces<SomeConcreteType>;

// type Case2 = {
//   relatedInterface?: RelatedInterface<string, ConcreteB>;
//   anotherRelatedInterface?: AnotherRelatedInterface<string, HTMLDivElement>;
// }
type Case2 = GetRelatedInterfaces<ThirdConcreteRelatedInterfaceVerbosely>;
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVR7lN)